# Recommend a HTTP component for Delphi 2010 allowing Range'd downloads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, http, delphi-2010

Can you advice me a shareware HTTP component for Delphi 2010?
I want to use it as HTTP multithread .exe file downloader.
I.e. one big .exe file will be downloaded in several threads.

Answer (score 8):

Indy (included with Delphi) is blocking, which I find makes it much easier to include in threads.

There are also the following freeware components:

- [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html) - non-blocking
- [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/start) - Blocking

Personally, I prefer Indy.  I have used and like ICS, and I have heard good things about Synapse.  You can't really go wrong.

UPDATE:

I see you've made the question more specific, asking for details on using [HTTP range](http://www.web-polygraph.org/docs/userman/ranges.html#Sect:4.2).

This can be done in Indy using the request.range property.  There is a working example [here](http://www.davinciunltd.com/2007/03/http-range-requests-in-delphi/).

Comment: ICS also has a demo (OverbyteIcsHttpMultipartDownload) included that does exactly what the OP is looking to do. I've used both Indy and ICS, and would recommend either. I too have heard good things about Synapse, but haven't used it personally. +1.

Comment: the `ContentRange...` properties are for receiving HTTP responses, not for sending HTTP requests.  The correct property to use to download ranged content is the `Request.Range` property instead.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can check [Clever Components Internet Suite](http://www.clevercomponents.com/downloads/inetsuite/suitedownload.asp) and see [Multi Downloader demo](http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/inetsuite/suitemmd.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Delphi 2010 yet, but I believe you can still import ActiveX type libraries. I've used MSXML2_TLB and WinHttp_TLB before to perform HTTP requests.

Comment: Why would you use ActiveX controls when there are native components that will do it as well (or better) and don't require external dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Some people don't like using third party components for Internet access.  If you prefer, you can use WinInet directly.

It's more verbose, but this can be used [from Delphi](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0080.htm).  And, of course, [HTTP Range is also supported](http://www.clevercomponents.com/articles/article015/resuming.asp).